# Transfer login between applications - Spring Security Core

Tags: spring, authentication, grails, spring-security

We have and application developed in Grails 2.3.11 using Spring Security Core 2.0 as authentication plugin.

Each application represents a different industrial project. Nowadays our client wants to implement a pre-login web to access the different projects transfering the login.

The user will log in in the pre-login web and it will charge a list of avalaible projects for this user, then, the user will click in the project selected and will be trasnfered directly to this project maintaining the login.

Is it possible? Wich method we should use?

- JSON authentication
- Remember-me cookie
- CAS Server using the Spring Security CAS plugin

Thanks.

Comment: I have a suggestion which can avoid the process of implementing two logins. Make user role groups based on projects (projectA group, projectB groups). Make a dashbord which is presented after login. This dashboard should show all of projects related to all those role groups of whose the user is member. You can implement this using spring security only.

Comment: When you say `each application represents a different industrial project`, what are these applications?  Are they a single web app running on a single domain (`www.example.com`), a single app serving multiple domains within a single top-level domain (`client.example.com`, `client2.example.com`, etc.), a single app serving multiple top-level domains (`www.foo.com`, `www.bar.com`, etc.) or multiple apps serving multiple domains?  The solution will vary based on your scenario.

Comment: @manish each pre-login web is exclusive for a client. For example, Client-1 will have a pre-login page with 1...n possible projects. I think the way we represent the domains will be project1.client.com, project2.client.com, projectn.client.com

Comment: @EjazAhmed but the pre-login webapp should be an independent app. We need to transfer the login or the session to the project webapp.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the pre-login with an external proxy like server. That proxy "forward" the login with every request to the application server in the http header. Then you can use spring-security pre-authorize filter.

See the image (Fig 1) of this [article](http://www.alimyftiu.com/2011/10/spring-security-tam/) for illusration. (Tam/ Junction is such a Proxy)

Comment: I see a problem in this implementation of the pre-login (please correct me if I am wrong). According to the Pre-Authetication Scenario "Note that when using a system like this, the framework performs no authentication checks at all and it is extremely important that the external system is configured properly and protects all access to the application. If an attacker is able to forge the headers in their original request without this being detected then they could potentially choose any username they wished." ¿How can I afford this?

Comment: @Adolfo Barroso: yes you are right. It is important that is is not possible to bypass the proxy! (anyway such systems exist in the real world)  - I have also seen some systems where the proxy generate some kind of token and add it to the forwarded request header, to verify that the request is "filtered" by the proxy.